# Data being inputted at end of line of the bookmark in MS Word not where it should be

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, openxml, bookmarks

I'm inputting data from the database to bookmarks in MS Word, every data is inputted right but the problem is that the data's location is inputted - for each related bookmark - at the end of the line and not where I added the bookmark, and I don't know why it's doing that!
I'm using opemXml on C#

### **Update**

```
    //  Get the main document part (document.xml).
    foreach (System.IO.Packaging.PackageRelationship documentRelationship in package.GetRelationshipsByType(documentRelationshipType))
    {
        NameTable nt = new NameTable();
        nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
        nsManager.AddNamespace("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

    Uri documentUri = PackUriHelper.ResolvePartUri(new Uri("/", UriKind.Relative), documentRelationship.TargetUri);
    documentPart = package.GetPart(documentUri);

    #region Update Document Bookmarks
    //Get document xml
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    //xdoc.Load(documentPart.GetStream());
    xdoc.Load(documentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

    //Select all bookmark nodes
    XmlNodeList nodeList = xdoc.SelectNodes("//w:bookmarkStart", nsManager);
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "DepositNO", GetDepositNO(DepositNo))) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "AppDate", FormFunctions.Get_Application_Date(DepositNo).ToShortDateString())) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "Title", FormFunctions.Get_Application_Title(DepositNo, 0))) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "ApplicantName", Get_Application_CV_Name(AppID, 6))) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "AgentName", Get_Application_CV_Name(AppID, 7))) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "Address", Address)) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "AgentName01", Get_Application_CV_Name(AppID, 7))) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "Times", Times)) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "A", A)) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "B", B)) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "Approve", Approve)) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "RequestArabic", RequestArabic)) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "ExamTime", ExamTime)) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "Mark", Mark)) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "Fees", Fees)) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "Objection", Objection)) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "Rejection", Rejection)) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "ExamTime01", ExamTime)) continue;
        if (this.SetBookmarkText(xdoc, node, "DepositNO01", GetDepositNO(DepositNo))) continue;
    }
    #endregion

    StreamWriter streamPart = new StreamWriter(documentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write));
    xdoc.Save(streamPart);
    streamPart.Close();
}

package.Flush();
package.Close();

//send response to browser
string File_Name = destenation + docFileName;

//string popupScript = "<script language='javascript'>" + "window.open('" + File_Name + "', 'Document', " + "'width=700, height=600, menubar=yes, resizable=yes')" + "</script>";
//ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "PopupScriptOffer", popupScript);

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + docFileName);
Response.WriteFile(File_Name);
Response.End();
```

### SetBookmarkText function

```
private bool SetBookmarkText(XmlDocument xdoc, XmlNode node, string bookmarkName, string bookmarkValue)
    {
        if (node.NextSibling.Name.ToString() == "w:bookmarkEnd")
        {
            if (node.Attributes["w:name"].Value == bookmarkName)
            {
                //get the node previous sibling style ("w:rPr") to apply to the bookmark text
                XmlNode nodeStyle = node.PreviousSibling.CloneNode(true);

            //parent node "w:p"
            XmlNode bookmrkParent = node.ParentNode;

            XmlElement tagRun;
            tagRun = xdoc.CreateElement("w:r", nsManager.LookupNamespace("w"));
            bookmrkParent.AppendChild(tagRun);

            if (nodeStyle.SelectSingleNode("//w:rPr", nsManager) != null)
                tagRun.AppendChild(nodeStyle.SelectSingleNode("//w:rPr", nsManager));

            XmlElement tagText;
            tagText = xdoc.CreateElement("w:t", nsManager.LookupNamespace("w"));
            tagRun.AppendChild(tagText);

            //*** insert text into part as a Text node 
            XmlNode nodeText;
            nodeText = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, "w:t", nsManager.LookupNamespace("w"));
            nodeText.Value = bookmarkValue;
            tagText.AppendChild(nodeText);

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I've posted the code. @Srinivas

Answer (score 0):

The replacement node for bookmark has been added to the end of parent node.

Replace the line

```
bookmrkParent.AppendChild(tagRun);
```

with

```
bookmrkParent.InsertAfter(tagRun, node);
```

Also this code expects your bookmark with empty text. ie., always the next node after the bookmark tag should be the bookmarkEnd. It will not work if you have some sample text as bookmark content.

Please replace few lines at the top like this

```
// if (node.NextSibling.Name.ToString() == "w:bookmarkEnd")
        {
            if (node.Attributes["w:name"].Value == bookmarkName)
            {
                    while (!node.NextSibling.Name.ToString().Equals("w:bookmarkEnd"))
                    {
                        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node.NextSibling);
                    }
......
```

If I come across more issues, will update.

Your logic has issues when the bookmark traverse beyond a single parent node. I'm still solving it.